# I'm attempting to run the Docker 'hello-world' app on a Google Cloud Compute VM instance but can't seem to access the output via the web browser

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm referring to the example located here: https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#requirementstxt
I'm able to successfully run the image on the server, but the resulting page isn't accessible when I navigate to my VM instance's IP address in the browser. Any idea what the issue could be?

Comment: are you able to get response of `curl http://localhost:4000` from the instance itself?

Comment: @chintanthakar, I see `<h3>Hello World!</h3><b>Hostname:</b> c75e5ce776ec<br/><b>Visits:</b> <i>cannot connect to Redis, counter disabled</i>` This is exactly what I expect to see.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can retrive successfully the page from localhost very likely you cannot access the webserver that is run inside docker in your VM due to firewall rules that inside Google Cloud Platform are whilisted for ingress traffic.

Notice that even if you tagged your VM with "HTTP-server" TAG at the moment of the creation of the VM it allows tcp:80 traffic only. You will need to [add a rule](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpc/firewalls) as well for tcp:4000.

Remember to tag the rule and add the tag to the VM from the 'edit VM' page, or add the rule for every instance in the subnet (even if it is not the best practise in production enviroments)

Comment: Yep - 100% agree it's a firewall rule issue.